# Why is my recursive function not using an updated state value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, recursion, react-hooks

I am trying to continually check if the current location of the user is within 100 meters of markers placed on a map.

I do this with a recursive function that checks all markers against current location with the haversine formula. When the recursive checkMarkers() function is first called, the array markers is empty.

With log statements I can see that the recursive function is still running, but when the state of markers changes, it is not reflected in checkMarkers().

```
const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
    checkMarkers();
useEffect(() => {

}, []);

const addMarker = marker => {
    const tempMarkers = [...markers];
    tempMarkers.push(marker);
    console.log(tempMarkers);
    setMarkers(tempMarkers);
  };

const checkMarkers = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(markers);
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
          for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            console.log(
              Haversine(
                {
                  latitude: markers[i].latitude,
                  longitude: markers[i].longitude,
                },
                {
                  latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                  longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                },
                {threshold: 100, unit: 'meter'},
              ),
            );
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
      );
      checkMarkers();
    }, 1000);
  };
```

I can add markers to an array and see them rendered on the map with:

```
<MapView ...>
  {markers.map((marker, i) => {
    return (
      <MapView.Marker
        key={i}
        coordinate={marker}
        onPress={() => removeMarker(i)}
      />
    );
  })}
</MapView>
```

So I can confirm that the  state is actually updaing.
I cannot figure out why when the next time checkMarkers() is executed, it still reads markers as an empty array (see log output below)

It seems checkMarkers() is reading the value when it was first called and not the current value.

How do I read the current value?

Console ouput:

```
[Info] 05-26 13:38:30.648 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []


[Info] 05-26 13:38:31.664 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []


[Info] 05-26 13:38:32.015 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: [ { longitude: 150.8891862630844, latitude: -34.42137027273215 } ]


[Info] 05-26 13:38:32.676 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []


[Info] 05-26 13:38:33.687 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []


[Info] 05-26 13:38:34.694 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []


[Info] 05-26 13:38:34.984 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: [ { longitude: [Getter/Setter], latitude: [Getter/Setter] },
05-26 13:38:34.984 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS:   { longitude: 150.89105676859617, latitude: -34.404266529657555 } ]


[Info] 05-26 13:38:35.713 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []


[Info] 05-26 13:38:36.735 27807 31324 I ReactNativeJS: []
```

Comment: Is something in `checkMarkers` supposed to update state? Like call `addMarker`? You seem to just call `checkMarkers` directly from the function body, likely an unintentional side-effect. When `checkMarkers` is called the entire recursive callstack is going to use the state from the render cycle the callstack exists in.

Comment: In the future, yes. But for this example it's only purpose is to print the Boolean value returned from Haversine()

Comment: Use component lifeceycle then. When do you want the `markers` state/haversine value logged out? OH, I see, are you just trying to log out the values once per second?

Comment: That's correct, I just want a true or false depending on whether the current location is within 100m of the marker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to log the state/haversine values once every second. Use a mounting `useEffect` hook to initiate an interval to call the `checkMarkers` callback and remember to return a cleanup function. Use a ref and additional `useEffect` hook to save a reference to the current state for use in the interval callback.

```
const markersRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  markersRef.current = markers;
}, [markers]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  const checkMarkers = () => {
    const markers = markersRef.current;
    console.log(markers);
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        markers.forEach(({ latitude, longitude }) => {
          console.log(
            Haversine(
              { latitude, longitude },
              {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              },
              {threshold: 100, unit: 'meter'},
            ),
          );
        });
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
    );
  };

  const intervalId = setInterval(checkMarkers, 1000);

  return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
}, []);
```